# Are there any special names given to the structures $\left<\mathbb{N}_0,+,\times\right>$ and $\left<\mathbb{N},+,\times\right>$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, terminology, semigroups

Following my grade school education, I will call the set $\mathbb{N}_0\equiv\left\{0,1,2,\dots\right\}$ the *whole numbers*, and the set $\mathbb{N}\equiv\left\{1,2,3,\dots\right\}$ the *natural numbers*.  The following is a list of what I believe to be the essential differences between the properties of $\left<\mathbb{N},+,\times\right>$ versus $\left<\mathbb{N}_0,+,\times\right>$:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{Law} & \text{op} & \text{Name} & \mathbb{N} & \mathbb{N}_{0}\\
a+\left(b+c\right)=\left(a+b\right)+c & \left[+\right] & \text{Associative} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
a+b=b+a & \left[+\right] & \text{Commutative} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
a+c=b+c\implies a=b & \left[+\right] & \text{Cancellative} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
a+0=a & \left[+\right] & \text{Identative} & \text{F} & \text{T}\\
0+0=0 & \left[+\right] & 0\text{--Idempotent} & \text{F} & \text{T}\\
a\times\left(b\times c\right)=\left(a\times b\right)\times c & \left[\times\right] & \text{Associative} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
a\times b=b\times a & \left[\times\right] & \text{Commutative} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
a\times c=b\times c\implies a=b & \left[\times\right] & \text{Cancellative} & \text{T} & \mathbb{N}\\
a\times1=a & \left[\times\right] & \text{Identative} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
a\times\left(b+c\right)=a\times b+a\times c & \left[\times\right] & \text{Distributive} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
1\times1=1 & \left[\times\right] & 1\text{--Idempotent} & \text{T} & \text{T}\\
0\times0=0 & \left[\times\right] & 0\text{--Idempotent} & \text{F} & \text{T}\\
0\times a=0 & \left[\times\right] & 0\text{--Degeneracy} & \text{F} & \text{T}
\end{array}$$

Thurston calls the additive algebraic structure $\left<\mathbb{N}_0,+\right>$ a *[hemigroup](https://archive.org/details/TheNumberSystem/page/n35)*.  This is also known as a *cancellative, commutative monoid.*

The additive algebraic structure $\left<\mathbb{N},+\right>$  is a *cancellative, commutative semigroup.*  I have no special name for this structure.

The multiplicative structure $\left<\mathbb{N},\times\right>$ is a hemigroup, but $\left<\mathbb{N}_0,\times\right>$ fails to be a hemigroup because $a\times 0=b\times 0$ is degenerate.  For a hemigroup the unique idempotent element can be shown to be the unique identity element. I find it modestly interesting that this applies to $\left<\mathbb{N}_0,+\right>$ and to $\left<\mathbb{N},\times\right>$ but not to the other two structures.

My question is this.  **Are there any special names given to the algebraic structures $\left<\mathbb{N},+,\times\right>$ determined by the natural numbers and $\left<\mathbb{N}_0,+,\times\right>$ determined by the whole numbers?**

I am also interested in any corrections to or obvious omissions in my list.

Comment: You mean semigroup. Thurston is right.

Comment: No. I mean **hemigroup.** https://archive.org/details/TheNumberSystem/page/n35

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I would advise not to use this term: it is highly non-standard, and apparently seems to be used for other, totally unrelated, structures: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02189348

Comment: I've seen the source you referenced.  But, so long as we are clear about our context, I don't see a compelling reason not to overload the definition.  I'm also considering calling a cancellative commutative semigroup a *natural semigroup.*  Then, perhaps I should call Thurston's hemigroup a *whole semigroup*.  Some m.se participants are actively disinterested in the comparison between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}_0$.  My previous request for references on the topic was voted down and out.  And I haven't found much in the way of meaningful discussion elsewhere.  I guess it's up to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me use a different notation. Let $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, \dotsm \}$ be the set of all natural numbers and let $\mathbb{N}_{> 0} = \mathbb{N} - \{0\} = \{ 1, 2, \dotsm \}$ be the set of positive integers.

Then $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{N}_{> 0}, +)$ are respectively the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) and the [free semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on one generator.
Moreover, $(\mathbb{N}, +, \times)$ is usually known as the [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) of natural numbers.